# How can I join Excel column and SQL View?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet, with one worksheet, with one column, containing key values I want to use to lookup data in a SQL Server view.

I can import the view data just fine using ADO or ODBC, but cannot figure out how to have the "Microsoft Query" tool add both the Excel Worksheet and the SQL View in a single query, so that I can join the data. I had also hoped VLOOKUP might lookup external data, but did not find anything,

I have looked for hours and am stumped. Certainly this can be done somehow where I can use a key in an Excel file to fetch a single related SQL table row back into Excel? I'm a hard core C# developer but seem to regularly struggle with Excel...

Answer (score 1):

I would  import the excel data into a staging table in your SQL Server database. 
Of course you can use ADO to get the excel data into SQL Server.

Then you can join the view with your staging table.

hope this helps.

Comment: I need to set this up for my boss so unfortunately, constantly importing new versions of the table into the database is not an option. Thanks though...

Comment: You can use a temporary table.